# Invoke method while creating an object

Tags: java, oop

Guys please tell me what is the construction when I call method while creating an object?

for example: Person p = new Person().get.....

Comment: the get is only called after the execution of the constructor, hence, after creating the object.

Comment: `Person p = new Person();` - unless you're being super broad..

Comment: Either way, either that get method returns an instance of Person, or it won't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create an Instance of the Object with new and call the Method while creating that Object than you can call that Method in the Constructor of that Objects Class

```
class Person {
  Person() {
    method();
  }
}
```

If you create your Object (Person) with this constructor the Method will be invoked.

If you want to call a Method after creating the Object.

```
Person person = new Person();
String name = person.getName();
```

or

```
String name = new Person().getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess patter Builder is what are you looking for

```
public class Computer {

    //required parameters
    private String HDD;
    private String RAM;

    //optional parameters
    private boolean isGraphicsCardEnabled;
    private boolean isBluetoothEnabled;


    public String getHDD() {
        return HDD;
    }

    public String getRAM() {
        return RAM;
    }

    public boolean isGraphicsCardEnabled() {
        return isGraphicsCardEnabled;
    }

    public boolean isBluetoothEnabled() {
        return isBluetoothEnabled;
    }

    private Computer(ComputerBuilder builder) {
        this.HDD=builder.HDD;
        this.RAM=builder.RAM;
        this.isGraphicsCardEnabled=builder.isGraphicsCardEnabled;
        this.isBluetoothEnabled=builder.isBluetoothEnabled;
    }

Computer comp = new Computer.ComputerBuilder(
                "500 GB", "2 GB").setBluetoothEnabled(true)
                .setGraphicsCardEnabled(true).build();
```

Comment: I doubt it, on a Builder, you wouldn't call a 'get' method, rather a 'with...' that passes a parameter. He might as well be researching method chaining

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing that comes to mind may be singleton, but it doesn't create new objects. Person p = Person().getInstance()?